# How to get users with similar term as current logged in user?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

On /admin/config/people/accounts/fields, I added several term reference fields, for example: profession/skill/interest. Now I need to show users with similar profession/skill/interests as current logged in user.
There is a [module similar by terms](https://www.drupal.org/project/similarterms), unfortunately, it does not support user entity.

Comment: You mean you need to list users who have similar terms to current user's terms, yes? If yes then what do you mean by *similar* ? it means exactly the same ? it least one? containing the terms?

Comment: "Similar" means the more same terms users have, the more similar they are.